# Cant set environment variables up with ionic?

Tags: angularjs, azure, ant, putty, ionic-framework

Herers my variables

ANDROID_HOME
variable: `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\android-sdk-windows`

JAVA_HOME
variable: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

PATH

variable: `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ant\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk_r24.0.2-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%;`

Now when I open putty and say echo `%PATH%` all I get back is "%PATH%"? Same for the other two? what am I doing wrong?

also when I try check the versions of ionic and cordova it just says no such file or dictionary? even tho I installed them?

```
  sudo npm install -g ionic
```

npm seems to be working too? I set up apache but it just says build failed and `build.xml` does not exist when i do `ant -v`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you also need to add an ANT_HOME system variable.  It should just be the path to the main Ant folder (not bin), C:\ant\apache-ant-1.9.4 based on your PATH variable.  As for putty and npm, I've never tried this and have only used Windows command line.

Answer (score 0):

echo %PATH% should return location of file system and not variable name.
Your JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME look correct.
But i don't think that @rrjohnson85 is correct for ANT, there isn't any batch files that are not in bin. Mine is set to: C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin and it works.

You should try to add environment variables with full URI of location on file system and not use other environment vars inside.

Comment: Ino path should return the location, so why is it not? I was told setting up ionic was easy but so far its been a massive pain.

Comment: Well problem is that documentation for PhoneGap is far from good, i had same problem several months ago when i was installing PG/Ionic.
I have the this variables:

**ANDROID_HOME, ANT_HOME, ANT_OPTS, JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** that contains:

`C:\Ruby21\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\ant\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Mladen\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`